# What are some ways that the environment might affect products being shipped in medieval times?

Tags: weather, transportation

I know if things are shipped need to be protected from the elements, but this is not entirely always possible. Methods of shipping also might affect things. Also as a side question, could these environmental changes to the products, actually improve them in some way?

When answering this question, keep in mind that environmental factors don't necessarily mean weather related. They could be such things as insects/ animals, heat/ humidity (affecting it indirectly), as well as plants/ seeds.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You may want to try narrowing it a bit.

Comment: @JBiggs would it help if I gave my own suggestions, to help narrow down what I already know?

Comment: @JesseCohoon I recommend changing it from 'How can the enviornment affect the products' to 'how can I protect these specific products from the enviornment.' I like the question, so I'm not voting to close, but that is my opinion of an appropriately narrow question.

Comment: what `things` are being shipped? What particular environments? What type of world (magic, just medieval)? Do you know what they used to ship `things` in the medieval ages and if so what are you looking for that is different?

Comment: @JesseCohoon Please do tell us what your "things" are. Fish? Meat? Cheese? Apples? Potatoes? Cloth? Medieval times are specialty of mine and each and every one of them were transported differently...

Comment: @JesseCohoon Suggest you edit and narrow the question. Tell us what the "things" are. Give us an idea of the landscape--are your things travelling by sea or river? Cart? List the possible methods of transport as well. And last, maybe name a geographical area for weather. In parts of Spain, and Italy the conditions there are much different than, say, England. If you narrow it thus, I think that will help.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but perhaps interesting anyway: I found a [map over midieval trading routes](http://etc.usf.edu/maps/pages/2400/2473/2473.htm), which could be of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Medieval times & Transporting Goods

**Fish**

To keep fish fresh, fish were often transported, alive from where they were caught, in the water they came from. This is a heavy way to transport, and not all the fish would survive. Fish were also smoked and pickled. This really depends on how far you are transporting goods and by which methods (overland, by ship, on a river).

**Produce**

This is highly dependant on the type of produce. Root vegetables like parsnip were popular and travelled well, as can apples. Leafy green produce or something more likely to rot was mostly locally grown and not transported too far, at least not over many days. Pickling, for many vegetables is only way to preserve things properly.  Grain, when dried properly, does travel well. As Catalyst says in their answer moisture is a big factor when it comes to grain. This can cause germination or mold.

**Meat**
The best way to preserve meat and transport it is not to kill it. Drive cattle to where you want to sell it, and then sell it. The buyer will butcher it. Otherwise, smoking and drying meat, to later put in stews and other applications, is the best way to go.

**Dairy**
Apocryphally, here's [the story of cheese](http://food.ndtv.com/lists/7-foods-that-were-accidentally-created-694740).

> Cheese is known to have been invented accidentally by an Arab
>   merchant. During his travels he carried milk in sacks that were made
>   of the stomachs of certain animals. As he traveled far and wide, the
>   heat of the sun activated rennin, an enzyme found in the stomach
>   lining. The bacteria made the milk curdle and separate into whey.

In this case the transport of the the milk actually made the cheese...
Hard cheeses do transport pretty well, and cheese can actually be a way to store protein that otherwise might spoil. (soft cheeses are a different matter, this applies mainly to hard cheese.

**Alcohol**
I suggest lots of research on this. Cort Ammon did a good job with the beer point in their answer. The higher the alcohol, the better it is for transport. Fortified wines and brandy are a result of people looking for a way to keep spoilage at bay for long periods.

**Cloth Goods/Wool**
Don't let it get wet. Should be fine in most instances. Bugs can eat cloth, but mainly if they are stored somewhere for a long time (or transported in an infested state.)

The bottom line on most things is: moisture and heat are the enemy.

Answer (score 2):

I think Erin Thurnsby's answer cover most aspects, but I wanted to add a more modern example. I think it might answer the question even though the actual transport was not done during medieval times.

[Monsoon Malabar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsooned_Malabar) is a way to treat coffee beans which was spoiled by modern means of transportation and now have to be done manually.

The trade route to India in late 1800 had to go all the way around Africa and took around six months. The high humidity from the ocean and rain for so long time caused coffee beans to ripen and change in their characteristics. The beans themselves changed colour from greenish to whiteish yellow and the acidity of the beans were more or less neutralized. This caused the brewed coffee to be very mild and, to quote the wikipedia text, "considered to be dry with a musty, chocolatey aroma and notes of spice and nuts".

This characteristic was lost with modern transport methods as the coffee beans were too well protected; nowadays it is produced by letting the beans ripen in casks during the monsoon period of the Malabar coast.

Comment: nifty & interesting! +1

Comment: Very nice story about coffee.  There's tea, too - I recall a story that there was at least one smoked tea that came about from traveling - "Russian Caravan" as it's called today, that was carried along trade routes and stored, and picked up smoke flavors from the campfires along the way, and that people liked enough to keep making.  Alternatively, there were smoked teas that came about through hastening preservation (drying using a campfire because it was wet outside and the shipment had to go = smoked tea).

Answer (score 1):

An environmental change is going to have no, positive, or negative effect. Clearly there have been many cases of positive effect.

Oak barrel imparts better taste.

Comment: @kingledion The stated question is could improve

Comment: @kingledion I take it you prefer the blanco tequilas, then. An añejo tequila needs to be stored in white oak barrels to mature properly.

Answer (score 1):

Many products are adjusted to meet their environment during shipping.  However, it will be hard to find a general pattern because the changes are *always* specific to that particular item being shipped and that particular mode of shipment.

A classic example is the India Pale Ale.  During the British Empire, Brits in India wanted a taste of home.  They wanted the beers brewed in England.  However, that's a really long journey for a beer.  They would risk spoiling along the way.  The solution was to cram the beer with as much hops as possible, because hops contains many natural preservatives.  The resulting beer was bitter, but had the taste of home the Brits wanted.  After that went on long enough, people developed a taste for this incredibly bitter beer, and the IPA was born.

Answer (score 1):

[Akvavit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akvavit) is traditionally aged in wooden casks aboard ships.  Supposedly the rocking motion aboard ship helps the aging process.  IMHO, much less certain is the basis for equator crossing to improve the spirits, but tradition apparently [sells](https://thornews.com/2012/01/13/linie-aquavit-crossing-the-equator-for-200-years/).

Moisture, whether fresh or salty is a major issue for many food crops: 
salt air might be good for aging some cheeses in the Parmesan/Romano style.

On the other hand, ship with a hold filled with grain, sailing on a freshwater river or lake/sea system, might have an undiscovered minor leak start grain germination en mass -- possibly swelling fast enough to burst the hull.  In a power/tech limited world, jettisoning large volumes of dampened grain quickly enough might be impossible, away from a port.